# Creating Custom List Forms for Creating, Editing, or Displaying a List Item

Tags: content-type, custom-form, user-controls, rendering-template

I'm following [this article](http://blog.beckybertram.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=6) (as well as different MSDN pages) and trying to add some custom template forms to my content type.

I think I'm doing all by the book, but for some reason  wont deploy my version of the content type.

Instead of my `XmlDocument` I get the default one which is:

```
 <XmlDocument NamespaceURI="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3/contenttype/forms">
      <FormTemplates xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3/contenttype/forms">
        <Display>ListForm</Display>
        <Edit>ListForm</Edit>
        <New>ListForm</New>
      </FormTemplates>
    </XmlDocument>
```

The `Display`, `Edit` and `New` entries are not my own. `ListForm` is the default.

My `.ascx` just contains some div with text in it. Just a test. It's in the right place in the CONTROLTEMPLATES folder.

What am I missing? How can I deploy with my custom templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. That happened with me whenever there is an issue with your templates. I forgot what was my exact reason but there has to be some issue with your templates.
2. Also, in order to override the templates, I realized, there is an Inherits attribute set to 'TRUE' in your definition for content type. Set that to 'FALSE' and it will pick your custom templates.

Comment: I'm marking this as the correct answer since the `Inherits="FALSE"` did the trick (unfortunately you loose the inherited fields so you have to add them by hand...). Seems this is a bug (http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010programming/thread/daac5dee-a283-4c8f-8275-46b412688066/).

Answer (score 0):

I think that you use incorrect rendering template ID. You should specify this id in your template. look at the excample:

```
<SharePoint:RenderingTemplate ID="CustomContentTypeCreateForm" runat="server">
```

Then you should use this id in your schema.

```
<FormTemplates  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3/contenttype/forms">
     <New>CustomContentTypeCreateForm</New>
   </FormTemplates>
```

In you case, I think, SharePoint looks for ListForm id and takes default template instead of your template.