# Workflow create task with content type - Custom Forms in InfoPath

Tags: workflow, infopath, content-type, custom-form

I know it's possible to [customize the forms of workflow tasks](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/sharepoint/StateMachineWorkflows2.aspx) but is it possible to have them customized also for "CreateTaskWithContentType" component, not just for "CreateTask"?

I [had a try of customizing the forms](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/24534/creating-custom-list-forms-for-creating-editing-or-displaying-a-list-item) of content types but was not successful so I thought that InfoPath forms might be an alternative. It works for normal tasks (workflow "CreateTask" component) but it seems it does not work for "CreateTaskWithContentType" (I get the default form for Task item, even if I set my content type as the default on the task list).

Is it possible to use "CreateTaskWithContentType" and have the forms customized with InfoPath?

Comment: Thanks for the post, I'm having the same issue? When my workflow was using the default workflow task my infopath Task forms where being rendered. As soon as I started using the CreateTask with Content Type activity the infopath task forms are no longer rendered in place of the default edit form.aspx for items. Wondering if you can specify exactly where in the article you reference is the solution to the problem? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve this by using this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms438856.aspx

Just one note about the article: WkTaskIP.aspx is in fact WrkTaskIP.aspx and is located in "_layouts" folder.

Comment: Thanks for the post, I'm having the same issue? When my workflow was using the default workflow task my infopath Task forms where being rendered. As soon as I started using the CreateTask with Content Type activity the infopath task forms are no longer rendered in place of the default edit form.aspx for items. Wondering if you can specify exactly where in the article you reference is the solution to the problem? Thanks for your help

Comment: @Sam: It's was this phrase that jolted my brain: `In the content type definition of the task's content type, add an XMLDocument element that specifies the custom edit and/or display forms` so I added something like `<XmlDocuments><XmlDocument NamespaceURI="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3/contenttype/forms/url"><FormUrls xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3/contenttype/forms/url"><Display>...WrkTaskIP.aspx</Display><Edit>...WrkTaskIP.aspx</Edit><New>...WrkTaskIP.aspx</New></FormUrls></XmlDocument></XmlDocuments>`. That was my problem; your problem might differ!